# Select count, inner joins and where statements

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is erp.orders:

```
userId  paidAt
1       2017-06-30
1       2017-06-18
2       2017-06-07
4       2017-06-07
3       2017-01-01
2       2017-01-01
2       2017-01-01
2       2017-01-01
```

This is prod.referral_order_delivered

```
user_id
1
2
```

This request :

```
select distinct erp.orders."userId", count(erp.orders."userId")
from erp.orders
inner join prod.referral_order_delivered
on erp.orders."userId"::uuid = prod.referral_order_delivered.user_id::uuid
where
   erp.orders."paidAt"::date >= '2017-06-07'
   and erp.orders."paidAt"::date <= '2017-07-07'
group by erp.orders."userId"
```

will give me this result:

```
userId  count
1       2
2       1
```

This is not the result I want. Among the ids that paid between 2017-06-07 and 2017-07-07 and that are in the table prod.referral_order_delivered, I want to count how many times they appear in the table erp.orders IN TOTAL. 
In my current request, I only count from 2017-06-07 to 2017-07-07.

The result I want is :

```
userId  count
1       2
2       4
```

See how userId 3 and 4 are excluded. This is really important. Could you modify my request, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try splitting up your problem. You want:

> the ids that paid between 2017-06-07 and 2017-07-07 and that are in the table prod.referral_order_delivered

and

> to count how many times they appear in the table erp.orders IN TOTAL

You already have the former:

```
select distinct erp.orders."userId"
from erp.orders inner join prod.referral_order_delivered
on erp.orders."userId"::uuid = prod.referral_order_delivered.user_id::uuid
where
   erp.orders."paidAt"::date >= '2017-06-07'
   and erp.orders."paidAt"::date <= '2017-07-07'
```

and the latter simply uses an inner-select:

```
select erp.orders."userId", count(erp.orders."userId")
from erp.orders
where
   erp.orders."userId" in (select ...)
group by erp.orders."userId"
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
     SELECT erp.orders."userId" 
           ,count(erp.orders."paidAt")
       FROM erp.orders
 INNER JOIN prod.referral_order_delivered
         ON erp.orders."userId"::uuid = prod.referral_order_delivered.user_id::uuid
        AND erp.orders."paidAt"::date >= '2017-06-07'
        AND erp.orders."paidAt"::date <= '2017-07-07'
   GROUP BY erp.orders."userId"
```

Comment: It doesn't give me the result I want.

Comment: add some test data with a rextester link

Comment: I didn't know this tool. Thanks a lot! But I have really found the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `having` clause instead of a `where` clause:

```
select o."userId", count(o."userId")
from erp.orders o inner join
     prod.referral_order_delivered rod
     on o."userId"::uuid = rod.user_id::uuid
group by o."userId"
having sum( (o."paidAt"::date >= '2017-06-07' and o."paidAt"::date <= '2017-07-07')::int) > 0;
```

Comment: Your solution works but I don't understand it as well as John Diamond's one.

Answer (score 1):

When you use inner join you are discarding info that you need in the "WHERE" clause later on. Because it creates a temporal resulting table in which you omit the entries here:

```
where
   erp.orders."paidAt"::date >= '2017-06-07'
   and erp.orders."paidAt"::date <= '2017-07-07'
```

So what you need to do is using semi-join instead as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT erp.orders."userId", COUNT(erp.orders."userId")
FROM erp.orders
WHERE erp.orders."userId" IN (
    SELECT erp.orders."userId"
    FROM erp.orders, prod.referral_order_delivered
    WHERE erp.orders."userId"::uuid = prod.referral_order_delivered.user_id::uuid
    AND erp.orders."paidAt"::date >= '2017-06-07'
    AND erp.orders."paidAt"::date <= '2017-07-07'
);
GROUP BY erp.orders."userId"
```

hope it helps!

Comment: Ok it looks like the same solution as John. Thanks!